# Loop through csv file and build json file in python

Tags: json, csv

Have a csv file with 3 columns
Col1 : SCHEMA
col2 : TABLENAME
col3 : COLUMNNAME

There are going to be around 10k rows in them. Need a script to roll through the csv and create a json as below and keep appending the same json until the last.

I want to build a json block as below :-

```
{
  "name": "SCHEMA.TABLENAME",
  "table_manipulation": {
    "owner": "SCHEMA",
    "name": "TABLENAME",
    "transform_columns": [{
      "column_name": "COLUMNNAME",
      "action": "KEEP",
      "computation_expression": "replace($COLUMNNAME,\"'\",\"\")"
    }],
    "source_table_settings": {
      "unload_segments": {
        "ranges": {},
        "entry_names": {}
      }
    }
  }
},
```

As for script - python would be best would powershell would work also.
Any help will be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't specify what language you wish to use to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks - updated with language - python or power shell would work.